# Why did my mango pickle become bitter?

Tags: mango

I dried the mango in sunlight, heated the oil and slightly roasted all masala before grinding it.
Now the problem is that masala taste bitter.

How can I fix it?
The masala I used includes salt, rye seed, methi [fenugreek] seed, saunf [fennel], turmeric powder and black seed [nigella].

Answer (score 3):

My first thought would be you over-roasted the methi.

Fenugreek seeds benefit from a light roasting or bhuna which removes the slight bitter edge they have - however, if you over-do it that bitterness comes back with a vengeance.

To avoid the issue, I usually add fenugreek powder to my sauce as it's cooking. It still develops the full aroma that way. It adds a very slight bitterness, but removes the danger of over-roasting right at the start & not finding out til right at the end.

I'm not sure it can be 'fixed' as such, other than by trying to balance [or really mask] it with sweetness, more acidity, or trying to dilute it in a larger batch.

Answer (score 0):

the real answer is the mustard seeds are old and hence they have turned bitter.

Only solution is to add lemon juice for the part quantity and only at the last minute of serving the pickle.

Comment: Welcome to SA!  It's unclear how your answer applies to the question, which does not include mustard seed.  Maybe take another look at it?